# Regex time maior que 00:00

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

Estou desenvolvendo uma validação regex utilizando o `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` e `RegularExpression` do asp.net mvc C#, neste regex é necessário validar tempo de duração sem limites em horas e o tempo deve ser maior que `00:00`, ou seja, podendo ser aceito valores a partir de `00:01` respeitando os limites de minutos(59) e segundos(59).

Consegui chegar até em: `\d{1,}:[0-5][0-9]`

```
04:00 -- true
00:01 -- true
00:23 -- true
00:04 -- true
04:00 -- true
01:00 -- true
23:00 -- true
21:00 -- true
1:00  -- true
00:61 -- false
00:00 --> problema
57:59 -- true
123:59 -- true
```

Como se trata de um formulário, estou apenas validando um horário e não um conjunto de valores, conforme a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de uma ajuda de como negar o valor `00:00` neste regex. Como ele fica em um RegularExpression no DataAnnotations, ou seja vinculado no meu model "Duracao", preciso que se encaixe em apenas uma validação:

```
[RegularExpression("^(\d{1,}:[0-5][0-9])$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "CampoObrigatorio")]
public string Duracao { get; set; }
```

Comment: Minha regex valida apenas hh:mm, sendo que horas pode ser infinita.

Comment: é em C#, fica em um System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations RegularExpression

Comment: Sim é pra verificar.

Comment: Entendi, adicionei no corpo de pergunta, é apenas um horário e não um conjunto de horários.

Comment: Boa noite, alguma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema? Se sim, marque a resposta que melhor lhe ajudou como correta, se não especifique qual o problema ocorreu ao tentar as soluções propostas.

Answer (score 3):

Use a expressão regular `^((?!0+:00)\d{1,}:[0-5][0-9])$`

Como você pode ver é praticamente igual a sua, com uma adição que impede o match de ser `"0:00"` nem `"00:00"` e nem `"0000:00"`.

A estrutura que eu usei é chamada de *"Negative lookahead"*, o que significa:

- Negative = é a negação do que está descrito
- Lookahead = a direção da negação, que é para frente

Sendo assim `(?!0+:00)` significa: **neste ponto, ao olhar para frente, não pode ser possível dar match em `0+:00`**. Note ainda que esta estrutura é uma assertiva, ela não consome os caracteres da string, e por isso é possível seguir com a expressão regular original sua `\d{1,}:[0-5][0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

Usando o `set;` e `get;` no seu caso, você pode criar uma "REGEX mista", seria algo como:

```
^(00:[0-5][1-9]|00:[1-5][0-9]|0[1-9]+[:][0-5][0-9]|[1-9]+[:][0-5][0-9])$
```

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
[RegularExpression("^(00:[0-5][1-9]|00:[1-5][0-9]|0[1-9]+[:][0-5][0-9]|[1-9]+[:][0-5][0-9])$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "CampoObrigatorio")]
public string Duracao { get; set; }
```

Explicando o REGEX:

- `00:[0-5][1-9]` valida horários do tipo 00:01 até 00:59, não valida 00:10, 00:20, 00:30, etc, por isto usa a próxima regra
- `00:[1-5][0-9]` valida horários do tipo 00:10 até 00:59 (valida só do tipo 00:xx então testa a próxima)
- `0[1-9]+[:][0-5][0-9]` valida horários acima de 01:00 até 09:59
- `[1-9]+[:][0-5][0-9]` valida horários acima de 09:59

---

Você também pode usar validar horário maior que `00:00` usando duas REGEX diferentes dentro do método:

Uma para verificar se o horário é `00:00`:

```
String horarios = "00:00";
Regex ct1 = new Regex(@"^0+:00$"); //00:00 ou 00000:00 são inválidos
If (!ct1.IsMatch(horarios) {
    //Not found 00:00
} else {
    //Invalid hour
}
```

E outra só para verificar o horário:

```
^\d\d+:\d{2}$
```

O resultado final seria algo como:

```
String horarios = "00:00";
Regex ct1 = new Regex(@"^0+:00$"); //00:00 ou 00000:00 são inválidos
Regex ct2 = new Regex(@"^\d+:[0-5][0-9]$");//Valida qualquer horário

If (!ct1.IsMatch(horarios)) {//Se algo como 00:00 ou 00000:00, invalida o código
   If (ct2.IsMatch(horarios)) {
       //Validou
   } else {
       //Hora invalida
   }
} else {
   //Hora invalida
}
```

> Note: Como não é uma "lista" de horários use o sinal `^` no começo e o `$` no final da REGEX

Comment: tentei usar, mas existem valores inválidos que nao podem passar: 00:61 123:78

Comment: @Cleber sobre o "limite", você não especificou na questão. 123:78  é o limite máximo?

Comment: Desculpe. Não tem limite em horas. Gostaria apenas que a duração fosse maior que 00:00 para retornar mensagem de erro no formulário.

Comment: @Cleber 00:01 já seria válido então? Você deve especificar tudo isso na PERGUNTA por favor, o StackOverflow é um Q&A e não um fórum, deixar a questão com mais detalhes e ao mesmo tempo clara é o minimo para se obter respostas. Grato

Comment: Tudo bem amigo, esse é meu primeiro "Q&A". Poderia relevar um pouco. Grato.

Comment: @Cleber não estou sendo grosso, só estou pedindo que edite a questão para que seja possível entender o que você necessita. Grato

Comment: Efetuei a edição conforme suas dicas, espero detalhado para via de colaboração. Obrigado.

Comment: @Cleber eu notei que você quer implementar a regra no metodo `set` `get`, então editei a resposta.